Can LED lights make chirping sounds?
Can LED light chirp like a smoke detector with a low battery? It chirps in my kitchen every 20 seconds. I have removed all moderators and turned off the power. I can not find where the chirping sound comes from. Could it be the LED lights in the ceiling? The sound comes from there somewhere.

An LED light shouldn't make any noise, except for possibly a low hum (some, particularly with dimmers). And if you have power off then there should be no noise at all. Which means:

Smoke detector
Some other device with a low battery
A prank chirping device:


It is often very hard to identify the direction/location of a noise. Keep looking...

you can use a voiceprint phone app to triangulate the source. Lay it somewhere, record for 20-40 seconds to capture the chirp, then move and re-measure and compare the volume to the first. repeat as needed.
